# how to tell dynamically if object exists, from a string variable

Tags: javascript

I Would like to tell if an object has been successfully created when loaded in via ajax call to an external javascript at run time. This is required because the loaded script can sometimes process data for 20 seconds prior to creating a global scoped variable (that is can have various names), and i need to wait until that script has finished prior to using the object.

i would like a function i could call that would behave like this

```
function is_object_loaded( objectname )
{
 if (typeof objectname !== "undefined" ) {
      // do  something
  }
}

is_object_loaded("demographic_pail");
```

obviously i need to turn objectname into something other than a string; and i refuse to eval unless its totally unavoidable.

Thanks!

Comment: add: }else{ return setTimeout(is_object_loaded.bind(this, objectname),100);}

Comment: `if (typeof window[objectname] !== "undefined")` should work, as far as that goes... but why not use a callback function at the end of the loaded script? Why poll for the object when you can just be called when it's *known* to exist?

Comment: I don't understand how, but the script returns with success in the callback well before the object is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function is_object_loaded( objectname ) {
  if (typeof window[objectname] !== undefined) {
      // do  something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could user `async:false` property of `ajax` and everything waits until that ajax is executed

```
 $.ajax({
  ....
  async:false,
  });
```